# Call to undefined function mysqli()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The issue occurs with this code

```
<?php
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','censored');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','censored');

$dbc = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
?>
```

I have installed php7.0-mysqli but I still get this error message

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli() in /var/www/html/actions/create_account.php:29\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/actions/create_account.php on line 29, referer: http://localhost/register.php
```

Here is phpinfo() output on mysqli.
[image]
What is going wrong?

Comment: change `mysqli ` to `mysqli_connect`

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI Thanks for your response. Aren't the functions synonymous? Anyway I tried it and got the same error.

Comment: @Anant Thanks for your response. I have added a screenshot of the phpinfo output on mysqli in the answer now. Any ideas?

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI  either he use your code or his he will face problem because it seems that

Comment: you need to check php version

Comment: "PHP Version 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1" according to phpinfo()

Comment: `if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';
} else {
    echo 'Phew we have it!';
}` check using this

Comment: "Phew we have it!"

Comment: Where did you get that mysqli() function?

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get install php-mysqlnd` and then restart apache

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI php7.0-mysql is already the newest version (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is crystal clear: there is no such function in PHP and never has been. There is only a function called *mysqli_connect*() and **class** called mysqli. But classes are not functions and have different syntax to handle

It means that, *according to the error message*, somewhere in the /var/www/html/actions/create_account.php on line 29 there is an improper call to mysqli

Comment: oh i got that sorry to bother you.

Comment: I hope that you learned a very important lesson today: an error message has a lot of important information and have to be read throughly.

Comment: yes, the problem is i didn't scroll and check the full error message (it happens today only). Usually i read full messages (Still i will remember it for future)